# Kotlin `split` giving different results in scripted and compiled mode

Tags: java, split, kotlin

I am having the following string (basically a raw HTTP request):

```
GET / HTTP/1.1            
User-Agent: Wget/1.19.1 (linux-gnu)                  
Accept: */*               
Accept-Encoding: identity 
Host: 0.0.0.0:5000        
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

It is stored in `this.requestData`. My function is something like:

```
println(this.requestData)                                                                                                                                                                         
var lines = this.requestData.split("\n")                                                                                                                                                          
println(lines)
```

this output I'm getting on compiling and running the program is:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1           
User-Agent: Wget/1.19.1 (linux-gnu)                  
Accept: */*               
Accept-Encoding: identity 
Host: 0.0.0.0:5000        
Connection: Keep-Alive    


, ]onnection: Keep-Aliveitylinux-gnu)
```

This means there's definitely something wrong with the `split` call. However if I test my code in the interactive shell:

```
$ kotlinc                                                                       
Welcome to Kotlin version 1.2.21 (JRE 1.8.0_151-8u151-b12-0ubuntu0.17.10.2-b12)                           
Type :help for help, :quit for quit                  
>>> var requestData = """GET / HTTP/1.1                                                                   
... User-Agent: Wget/1.19.1 (linux-gnu)                                                                   
... Accept: */*                                      
... Accept-Encoding: identity                        
... Host: 0.0.0.0:5000                               
... Connection: Keep-Alive                           
...                       
...                       
... """                   
>>> var lines = requestData.split("\n")
>>> lines
[GET / HTTP/1.1           , User-Agent: Wget/1.19.1 (linux-gnu)                  , Accept: */*               , Accept-Encoding: identity , Host: 0.0.0.0:5000        , Connection: Keep-Alive    , , , ]
```

I get the expected result. What am I missing here?

Comment: The carriage returns (CR or `\r`)? I think the output of your program is actually correct, but as the output contains CR characters but no line feed (LF or `\n`), each line overwrites the previous. Try splitting on `\r?\n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @haraldK in the comments, I got it working properly by splitting at `"\r\n"`